# How can you run loops alongside tkinter? - Python QR code reader GUI

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, raspberry-pi, qr-code

I am trying to write a Tkinter application that will also process QR codes. For that to work, I need to have a loop checking if the QR code is valid and I need to make a post request. I'm fully aware that the way I have coded this is highly inefficient. Is there a better way to do this? Here is what I have so far:

```
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import sys
import os
import pyzbar.pyzbar as zbar
import threading
import requests
import queue

result = []
decodedCode = ""

logo     = "logo.png"
settings = "settings.png"

if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
    print('no display found. Using :0.0')
    os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY', ':0.0')


#create main window
master = tk.Tk()
master.title("tester")
master.geometry("480x800")
master.configure(bg='white')
ttelogo = tk.PhotoImage(file = logo)
settingslogo = tk.PhotoImage(file = settings)

#settings button
settings_frame = tk.Frame(master,width=50,height=50,bg="white")
settings_frame.pack_propagate(0) # Stops child widgets of label_frame from resizing it
settingsBtn = tk.Button(settings_frame, image=settingslogo).pack()
settings_frame.place(x=430,y=0)

#logo
img = tk.Label(master, image=ttelogo, bg='white')
img.image = ttelogo
img.place(x=176.5,y=10)

#Name Label
label_frame = tk.Frame(master,width=400,height=100,bg="white")
label_frame.pack_propagate(0) # Stops child widgets of label_frame from resizing it
tk.Label(label_frame,bg="white",fg="black",text="John Smith Smithington III",font=("Calibri",22)).pack()
label_frame.place(x=40,y=140)

#Instructions Label
instructions_frame = tk.Frame(master,width=440,height=100,bg="white")
instructions_frame.pack_propagate(0) # Stops child widgets of label_frame from resizing it
tk.Label(instructions_frame,bg="white",fg="black",text="Place your pass under the scanner below.",font=("Calibri",10)).pack()
instructions_frame.place(x=20,y=210)

#Camera Window
cameraFrame = tk.Frame(master, width=440, height=480)
cameraFrame.place(x=20, y=260)

#Camera Feed
lmain = tk.Label(cameraFrame)
lmain.place(x=0, y=0)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def startScanning():
    global cap
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    lmain.after(10, startScanning)

def processScan():
    global decodedCode
    stopped = False
    delay = 1
    
    while(True):
        ret = cv2.waitKey(delay) & 0xFF
        if ret == ord('c'): # continue
            stopped = False
            delay = 1
        if ret == ord('q'):
            break
        if stopped or (ret == ord('s')): # stop
            stopped = True
            delay = 30
            continue

        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        decodedObjects = zbar.decode(frame)
        if len(decodedObjects) > 0:
            stopped = True
            for code in decodedObjects:
                #print("Data", obj.data)
                #API Calls
                decodedCode = code.data.decode('utf-8')

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def checkCode():
    global decodedCode
    while True:
        if decodedCode != "":
            print (decodedCode)
            result = requests.post("https://example.com/login/index.php", data={'action': 'validate_scan', 'uuid': decodedCode}).text
            print(result)
            decodedCode = ""

startScanning()  #Display 2
threading.Thread(name='background', target=processScan).start()
threading.Thread(name='background2', target=checkCode).start()
master.mainloop()  #Starts GUI
```

Edit: New version in queue form:

```
# import all the necessary modules
from tkinter import *
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from queue import Empty  # for excepting a specific error

import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import sys
import os
import pyzbar.pyzbar as zbar
import threading
import requests


# this is the function that will be run in a child process
def processScan(queue_):  # pass the queue as an argument
    stopped = False
    delay = 1
    
    while(True):
        ret = cv2.waitKey(delay) & 0xFF
        if ret == ord('c'): # continue
            stopped = False
            delay = 1
        if ret == ord('q'):
            break
        if stopped or (ret == ord('s')): # stop
            stopped = True
            delay = 30
            continue

        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        decodedObjects = zbar.decode(frame)
        if len(decodedObjects) > 0:
            stopped = True
            for code in decodedObjects:
                #print("Data", obj.data)
                #API Calls
                queue_.put(code.data.decode('utf-8'))

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    #master.after(2000, processScan)
    #return r


# just a function to not write a `lambda`, just easier
# to read code
def startScanning():
    global cap
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    lmain.after(10, startScanning)
    #processScan()
    #threading.Thread(name='background', target=processScan).start()
    # set process `daemon = True` so that it gets terminated with the
    # main process, this approach is not suggested if you write to file
    # but otherwise it shouldn't cause any issues (maybe an error but
    # that probably can be handled with `try/except`)
    Process(target=processScan, args=(queue, ), daemon=True).start()


# here is the loop for updating the label
# basically get the info from the queue
def update_label():
    try:
        # try getting data but since it is `block=False`
        # if there is nothing in the queue it will not block
        # this process waiting for data to appear in the queue
        # but it will raise the Empty error
        data = queue.get(block=False)
    except Empty:
        pass
    else:
        # if no error was raised just config
        # label to new data
        labelFrame.config(text=data)
    finally:
        # and simply schedule this function to run again in
        # 100 milliseconds (this btw is not recursion)
        master.after(100, update_label)

# crucial part is to use this if statement because
# child processes run this whole script again
if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = Tk()

    logo     = "logo.png"
    settings = "settings.png"

    if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
        print('no display found. Using :0.0')
        os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY', ':0.0')


    #create main window
    master.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    master.title("Title")
    master.geometry("480x800")
    master.configure(bg='white')
    ttelogo = PhotoImage(file = logo)
    settingslogo = PhotoImage(file = settings)

    #settings button
    settings_frame = Frame(master,width=50,height=50,bg="white")
    settings_frame.pack_propagate(0) # Stops child widgets of label_frame from resizing it
    settingsBtn = Button(settings_frame, image=settingslogo).pack()
    settings_frame.place(x=430,y=0)

    #logo
    img = Label(master, image=ttelogo, bg='white')
    img.image = ttelogo
    img.place(x=176.5,y=10)

    #Name Label
    label_frame = Frame(master,width=400,height=100,bg="white")
    label_frame.pack_propagate(0) # Stops child widgets of label_frame from resizing it
    Label(label_frame,bg="white",fg="black",text="John Smith Smithington III",font=("Calibri",22)).pack()
    label_frame.place(x=40,y=140)

    #Instructions Label
    instructions_frame = Frame(master,width=440,height=100,bg="white")
    instructions_frame.pack_propagate(0) # Stops child widgets of label_frame from resizing it
    Label(instructions_frame,bg="white",fg="black",text="Place your pass under the scanner below.",font=("Calibri",15)).pack()
    instructions_frame.place(x=20,y=210)

    #Camera Window
    cameraFrame = Frame(master, width=440, height=480)
    cameraFrame.place(x=20, y=260)

    #Camera Feed
    lmain = Label(cameraFrame)
    lmain.place(x=0, y=0)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    
    # define queue (since it is a global variable now
    # it can be easily used in the functions)
    queue = Queue()
    
    #label = Label(root)
    #label.pack()
    # initially start the update function
    update_label()
    
    # just a button for starting the process, but you can also simply
    # call the function
    #Button(root, text='Start', command=start_process).pack()
    startScanning()

    master.mainloop()
```

Still running into errors. Also am not sure if this is correct Queue syntax. The Camera feed is not live. Just a static image is showing up at the moment.

Comment: One optimization would be to use a `queue` to send codes from `processScan` into `checkCode`.  That way, `checkCode` can block when there's nothing to do, instead of using up 100% of a CPU in a tight loop.

Comment: Any change you could provide an example @TimRoberts? I tried doing a queue before and didn't have much luck. Thanks!

Comment: I also noticed that the CPU is almost at 200% when running these two threads...Highly inefficient at the moment. I am just not familiar on how to run things along with tkinter. I tried using the "master.after()" method, but that would not work either.

Comment: for cpu heavy tasks I have heard that `multiprocessing` is better since it spans processes over multiple cores, however `tkinter` itself can't be run on any child process, only the calculation parts and even then only objects that can be pickled, also for queues then you should use `multiprocessing.Queue` instead of `queue.Queue`

Comment: @Matiiss Any chance you could give me an example? I tried using a queue before, but didn't have much luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is about as simple as it gets with `multiprocessing` (explanation in code comments (which is why the code may seem like it has a lot going on when if the comments were removed it would be approx only 40 lines of code for this example)):

```py
# import all the necessary modules
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from queue import Empty  # for excepting a specific error


# this is the function that will be run in a child process
def count(queue_):  # pass the queue as an argument
    # these modules are just to show the functionality
    # but time might be necessary otherwise
    # if theses are imported in the global namespace
    # then you don't need to import them here again
    import itertools
    import time
    for i in itertools.count():
        # do the main looping
        # put data in the queue
        queue_.put(i)
        # you may not need to use sleep here depending
        # on how long it takes for the
        # loop to finish the iteration
        # the issue is that the loop may finish
        # way faster than the update function runs
        # and that will fill up the queue
        # I think the queue size can be limited
        # but putting sleep like this to allow
        # the update loop to update will work too
        time.sleep(0.2)


# just a function to not write a `lambda`, just easier
# to read code
def start_process():
    # set process `daemon = True` so that it gets terminated with the
    # main process, this approach is not suggested if you write to file
    # but otherwise it shouldn't cause any issues (maybe an error but
    # that probably can be handled with `try/except`)
    Process(target=count, args=(queue, ), daemon=True).start()


# here is the loop for updating the label
# basically get the info from the queue
def update_label():
    try:
        # try getting data but since it is `block=False`
        # if there is nothing in the queue it will not block
        # this process waiting for data to appear in the queue
        # but it will raise the Empty error
        data = queue.get(block=False)
    except Empty:
        pass
    else:
        # if no error was raised just config
        # label to new data
        label.config(text=data)
    finally:
        # and simply schedule this function to run again in
        # 100 milliseconds (this btw is not recursion)
        root.after(100, update_label)


# crucial part is to use this if statement because
# child processes run this whole script again
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    
    # define queue (since it is a global variable now
    # it can be easily used in the functions)
    queue = Queue()
    
    label = Label(root)
    label.pack()
    # initially start the update function
    update_label()
    
    # just a button for starting the process, but you can also simply
    # call the function
    Button(root, text='Start', command=start_process).pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

I am not too familiar with `opencv` so there might be a chance it won't work in a child process (tho I think I have done that), in that case you will have to either use `threading` or two alternatives using `subprocess`: put the `opencv` part in another file and run that file using python interpreter in the `subprocess.Popen` (won't work for computers that don't have `Python` installed) or convert that other python file with the `opencv` part to an `.exe` file or sth and run that executable file in the `subprocess.Popen` (both approaches tho are probably unnecessary and you probably will be fine with either `multiprocessing` or `threading`)

To use `threading` instead change these lines:

```py
# from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from threading import Thread
from queue import Empty, Queue
```

and

```py
# Process(target=count, args=(queue, ), daemon=True).start()
Thread(target=count, args=(queue, ), daemon=True).start()
```

Comment: multithreading should work just fine here. no need for multiprocessing. explicit subprocesses should be avoided.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz OP said sth about high CPU usage, something that `multiprocessing` should limit, no? either how, if using queues then the only difference would be to use queue from `queue` module and replace `Process` with `Thread` from `threading` library, basically change like 3 lines, if you wanted to use `Thread`. Otherwise is there really a difference in this case except for that `Process` would use its own resources and not slow down `tkinter` (out of curiosity)? Also are you saying that `subprocess.Popen` in this manner (as described in my answer) shouldn't be used?

Comment: Well, you need to understand your workload.  `multiprocessing` does not reduce the CPU utilization in any way.  Technically, it actually adds overhead.  What it does do is spread the processing demands to other CPUs.  Scanning an image for QR codes is a time-consuming task.  If you want to reduce the CPU load, you need to reduce the frame-per-second rate.

Comment: @TimRoberts ok, I think I finally understood. `multiprocessing` is suited for CPU bound tasks while `threading` - for IO bound tasks. From my understanding the task of checking a QR code would be IO bound, however neither module is meant to reduce CPU usage? they just allow to run code concurrently (necessary when using sth like `tkinter` (unless looping doesn't take much time)) and can reduce the time taken to do a task, however to reduce CPU usage, the code should be optimized or for this case run less times?

Comment: @TimRoberts  Btw would using `multiprocessing` for any kind of task speed up `tkinter` since the other process wouldn't use the resources of `tkinter` process?

Comment: I am having a hard time converting this example to fit my program. Any chance you can assist @Matiiss? Not really too good with Queue's.

Comment: @ToddMurphy btw what do you need a queue for? and when should something be put in it? like when it scans the code? or while scanning?

Comment: @Matiiss So the basic idea of the Python script is to have a webcam frame running in tkinter. As that's running, it has to continually check if a QR code enters the frame. If it does, it needs to decode it and then make a cURL request. Whatever is returned from the cURL request is updated into a label. That's the basic premise of the program. Not sure if something like that can be reformatted into queue syntax.

Comment: @Matiss `tkinter` does not need CPU.  A `tkinter` process spends its time waiting for clicks and keystrokes.

Comment: @ToddMurphy ok, so have you got the part that checks for qr code, sends a request and waits for the response? Well then simply put all that in the function and at the end put the response in the queue, just once presumably. You could at start at least try simply replacing the contents of `count()` with your qr reader loop and move the queue part to the end, probably outside of the loop and `data` wouls be the response

Comment: @Matiiss I tried to convert this to a queue. Could you please review that in the original question? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @ToddMurphy ok, and what is the issue exactly? I could guess that you should take `Process(target=processScan, args=(queue, ), daemon=True).start()` out of the `startScanning()` function because a process is started every 10 ms now because you are using `.after()`, so make another function that will start the loop and then create the process, basically one to start process and loop, one to loop like currently `startScanning()` and one that is another process. You also can't use `cap` in that process like this, you could however if you changed it to a Thread as mentioned in answer